# Highlighted Duplicated values , how to show in msgbox Ex:- duplicate Cell value(2) is duplicaed 3 times

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am searching for a way to show in msgbox a dynamic value.

Ex:- *duplicate Cell value(2) is duplicated 3 times*.

This is what I have written in my code:

```
'this function for to highlight duplicates
Function FindingDuplicate(rng As Range, counter As Long) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    'For each lopp for getting all cell values
    For Each cell In rng
     ' Checking the condition wheather cell value is reapted or not
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(rng(1, 1), cell), cell.Value) > 1 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            counter = counter + 1
        Else
            cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    Next
    FindingDuplicate = counter > 0
End Function   


'This is my Main()

 Sub main()
 Dim counter As Long
 'Calling Function 
 If FindingDuplicate(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, counter) Then '<--| change 'ActiveSheet.UsedRange' to whatever range you want
    MsgBox counter & " cells (red background) contain a duplicated data. Please Check"

Else
    MsgBox " Data Validation Completed. No Duplicate Found."
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to use `Dictionary` object (in your VBA IDE click Tools->References, scroll down the "Available references" listbox till "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" entry and tick its check mark, finally click "OK" button)

```
Function FindingDuplicate(rng As Range, nDupes As Long, dupes As Scripting.Dictionary) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dupesCounter As Long

    For Each cell In rng
        dupesCounter = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(rng(1, 1), cell), cell.Value) - 1
        If dupesCounter > 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            dupes.Item(cell.Value) = dupesCounter
        Else
            cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    Next
    FindingDuplicate = dupes.count > 0
End Function
```

so that your "Main" sub becomes:

```
Sub main()
    Dim nDupes As Long
    Dim dupe As Variant
    Dim dupes As Scripting.Dictionary '<--| declare a 'Dictionary' object

    Set dupes = New Scripting.Dictionary '<--| instantiate the 'Dictionary' object
    'Calling Function
    If FindingDuplicate(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, nDupes, dupes) Then '<--| change 'ActiveSheet.UsedRange' to whatever range you want
        With dupes
            For Each dupe In .keys
                MsgBox "duplicate cell value (" & dupe & ") is duplicated " & .Item(dupe) & " times"
            Next
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox " Data Validation Completed. No Duplicate Found."
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: LOL, thinking of the same concept and typing the same speed

Comment: @user3598756 whats ur name sir can u please tell ur name

Comment: @user3598756 and thnk u so much once again

Comment: @user3598756 yes, this time you got the tick

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you want, you want to have a dynamic field in your message box, containing the value of the variable you defined. To do so you can try

```
MsgBox( Counter & " cells (with red background) contain duplicate data. Please check!")
```

Where Counter is the dynamic field. If, let's say, Counter = 3, you will get `"3 cells (with red background) contain duplicate data. Please check!"`. If this works, you can tailor it to show the specific text you want to display.

Comment: Yes Iam using that only ,  but i wnt msgbox give msg like MsgBox duplicate values are 2 repeated 3 times , 4 repeated 2 time  . Like this

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for the insight. I edited the answer to (hopefully) provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `Dictionary`.

First, loop thorugh your Worksheet("SheetName"), and not `ActiveSheet`, and find all unique values (without empty cells), and store them in the `Dictionary`.

After, loop thorugh `Dictionary.Keys`, and per each unique key search your range to see how many duplicates exist (if you want to show all duplicate values inside the range).

I modified your `Function` a little, so it will return the number of duplicates, and then back in the `main Sub`, if the `counter > 1` then display the "Duplicates" `MsgBox` and how many times it was found inside the Range.

**Code**

```
'this function for to highlight duplicates
Function NumOfDuplicates(rng As Range, Lookfor As Variant) As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    NumOfDuplicates = 0 ' init value

    ' Checking the condition wheather cell value is reapted or not
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = Lookfor Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Lookfor) > 1 Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                NumOfDuplicates = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Lookfor)
            Else
                cell.Interior.pattern = xlNone
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Function

'=====================================================================      
'This is my Main()
Sub main()

Dim counter As Long
Dim C As Range
Dim Dic As Object, Key As Variant
Dim Dup As Boolean
Dup = False '<-- init flag

' --- create a dictionary to save all unique values in range ---
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- replace "Sheet1" with your sheet's name (don't use ActiveSheet)
    For Each C In .UsedRange
        If C.Value <> "" Then
            If Not Dic.exists(C.Value) Then
                Dic.Add C.Value, C.Value '<-- add unique values to dictionary
            End If
        End If
    Next C

    For Each Key In Dic.Keys ' <-- loop through unique keys
        'Calling Function
        counter = NumOfDuplicates(.UsedRange, Key)
        If counter > 1 Then
            Dup = True
            MsgBox "Duplicate value " & Key & " found " & counter & " times (red background). Please Check"
        End If
    Next Key

    If Dup = False Then MsgBox "Data Validation Completed. No Duplicate Found."
End With

End Sub
```